# HC progression path in MoP

Tags: world-of-warcraft

What's the optimal (the easiest) progress path (order of bosses killed) for heroic raids in Mists of Pandaria in tier 14?
I'm mainly interested in 10 men HC.

Comment: Please consider removing all of the abbreviations so the question is more clear to everyone.

Comment: @James With all due respect, but it's common knowledge among Blizzard's community. More or less, it's like going to superuser and saying - don't write CPU, use full name. I could argue that most people are more familiar with abbreviations then with long forms.

Comment: Respect is fine and all that but in general with every other game on here where acronyms are common, for instance LoL, we do ask that people spell them out completely as it does make for a better question and answer that is more widely applicable to both new users and veterans of long running games like them.

Comment: @James there isn't a single abbreviation in this question which isn't used in its full form somewhere else within the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on [numbers of kills](http://www.wowprogress.com/) (10 and 25 man combined) it looks like the progression path is like follows:

1. Heroic Mogu'shan Vaults: Stone Guard
2. Heroic Mogu'shan Vaults: Feng the Accursed
3. Heroic Mogu'shan Vaults: Gara'jal the Spiritbinder
4. Heroic Mogu'shan Vaults: Elegon
5. Heroic Heart of Fear: Blade Lord Ta'yak
6. Heroic Mogu'shan Vaults: Four Kings
7. Heroic Heart of Fear: Wind Lord Mel'jarak
8. Heroic Mogu'shan Vaults: Will of the Emperor
9. Heroic Heart of Fear: Garalon
10. Heroic Heart of Fear: Imperial Vizier Zor'lok
11. Heroic Heart of Fear: Amber-Shaper Un'sok
12. Heroic Terrace of Endless Spring: Lei Shi
13. Heroic Terrace of Endless Spring: Protectors of the Endless
14. Heroic Heart of Fear: Grand Empress Shek'zeer
15. Heroic Terrace of Endless Spring: Tsulong
16. Heroic Terrace of Endless Spring: Sha of Fear

There is more Heroic Stone Guard kills than Normal Grand Empress Shek'zeer and Sha of Fear kills. This could be because it is easier than the 2 bosses on normal or because it has been out longer. But it looks like it is around the time you are missing one of thous bosses on normal you should start on heroic.

Most guilds will push for kills in the order that the bosses occur in, so the list will of course also reflect that (since it is ordered by number of guilds that have killed the boss), and the team composition you have available may also affect your preferred path.

For 10 man only kills the list is changed a bit:

1. Heroic Mogu'shan Vaults: Stone Guard
2. Heroic Mogu'shan Vaults: Feng the Accursed
3. Heroic Mogu'shan Vaults: Gara'jal the Spiritbinder
4. Heroic Mogu'shan Vaults: Elegon
5. Heroic Mogu'shan Vaults: Four Kings
6. Heroic Heart of Fear: Blade Lord Ta'yak
7. Heroic Mogu'shan Vaults: Will of the Emperor
8. Heroic Heart of Fear: Wind Lord Mel'jarak
9. Heroic Heart of Fear: Garalon
10. Heroic Heart of Fear: Imperial Vizier Zor'lok
11. Heroic Heart of Fear: Amber-Shaper Un'sok
12. Heroic Terrace of Endless Spring: Lei Shi
13. Heroic Terrace of Endless Spring: Protectors of the Endless
14. Heroic Heart of Fear: Grand Empress Shek'zeer
15. Heroic Terrace of Endless Spring: Tsulong
16. Heroic Terrace of Endless Spring: Sha of Fear

Comment: Yeah, my mistake, I forgot to write down I'm interested in 10 men raids. Nevertheless, thanks, +1.

Comment: I don't mind getting a down vote if there is something wrong. But could you please add a comment about what you think is wrong when down voting?

Comment: Just going to point out that this is wrong. The fact is, that you can "NOT" progress to the next boss on heroic difficulty without killing the previous boss on heroic at least once. For this question, this difficulty structuring completely invalidates the given answer. As for standard farming for gear, this answer would be correct, as those are the bosses that are killed more for drops than for progression. And boss data has never been listed by the amount of guilds that have killed them, they are listed by number of total downs, by guild/pug/what have you.

Comment: @Ravekner Some bosses do require you to kill the previous to proceed on heroic, but some of them you can skip, a good example is Four Kings and Elegon where a lot of guilds revers progression order. Did you even look at the link I posted? it shows how many guilds have taken it down, not number of times it have been killed, though if two guilds went together (split evenly) and killed a boss on 25 man it would show as two 10 man kills, but i doubt that happens a lot.

Comment: Honestly mate, if blizzard changed it so that you can do a boss out of order, then there is no reason for heroic to be considered progression. Progression is the completion of each boss in the order they appear with in the raid, if the raid gives multiple wings to clear(i.e.- Icecrown Citadel) then the guild can choose in which order they attempt each set of bosses. Mogu'shan Vaults, Heart of Fear and Terrace of the Endless Springs however do not have these options. Which means guilds are taking advantage of a broken system, not progressing legitimately.

Comment: You can hash it anyway you want, but that is the truth of the matter. And by the way, you can't even get to Elegon without killing the Spirit Kings. The door down to his room doesn't open until the Spirit Kings have been defeated. So please tell me again how people are legitimately doing Heroic Elegon before downing Heroic Spirit Kings.

Comment: Very simple, they kill Spirit Kings on normal, go to Elegon and then change the instance to heroic. There is no special trick for it, once you have unlocked heroic version of a dungeon many of the non final boss can be killed on heroic with out killing others. In Heroic Terrace of Endless Spring Nearly 2x the Guilds have killed Lei Shi (the 3rd boss) than Protectors of the Endless(1st boss).

Comment: That is not progression then. You don't get to skip a boss by doing it on normal, and then kill the following boss on heroic and say you have progressed to that boss, because you haven't. Again, this is players taking advantage of a broken system. It would be like a guild clearing Lich King on 10 man normal, and then clearing the entire raid again on normal and doing Lich King on Heroic. That's not progression. (I know that example is a little extreme, but it shows the general point)

Comment: @Ravekner Have you considered providing your own answer? :)

Comment: @Ravekner you do not have to kill bosses in order on heroic in order to try the next boss on heroic in some instances - the best example of this is guilds doing Spirit Kings on normal and then progressing Elegon on heroic. "Progression Raiding" only ever really cared about who kills the last boss of the tier on heroic anyway when it comes down to it.